# Can google spreadsheets take the like count of a Tik-Tok using the basic web functions (IMPORTHTML(), IMPORTDATA(), IMPORTXML(), etc.)

Tags: google-sheets, tiktok

I am attempting to use google spreadsheets to organize some marketing information for a very small non-profit I volunteer for. Rather than manually inputing data like the number of likes and comments, I am trying to find a way to just take the number displayed when the given link is loaded. Google's documentation shows that ImportHTML can do this for data tables in wikipedia, and using the inspect tool I can find the like-count displayed as plain text. Is there an easy way to get this number using googles built in tools?

I have attempted to use API Connector to get the information, but tik-tok is not available. Would I be better off just manually adding this data?

Comment: Something like this could work:

https://old.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/127b39p/need_a_solution_for_scraping_tiktok_data/